# Javascript Regex to return only a range of items

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a requirement were the regex expression should only return the immediate children of it's parent. For eg.
If parent is denoted by classname 
"level-0", 
it's immediate children classname can be 
"level-0-0, level-0-1......,level-0-10" etc.

I have a regex in javascript that is intended to return only the immediate child, but it's not working. Please find the regex below.

```
$('tr').filter(function(){
  return this.className.match(/level-0[-\d+]{1,1}/)
}) // The result below.
[<tr class=​"fundRow level-0-0 child" style=​"display:​ table-row;​">​…​</tr>​, <tr class=​"fundRow level-0-0-0 child" style=​"display:​ table-row;​">​…​</tr>​, <tr class=​"fundRow level-0-0-0-0 child" style=​"display:​ table-row;​">​…​</tr>​, <tr class=​"fundRow level-0-0-0-1 child" style=​"display:​ table-row;​">​…​</tr>​, <tr class=​"fundRow level-0-0-1 child" style=​"display:​ table-row;​">​…​</tr>​, <tr class=​"fundRow level-0-1 child" style=​"display:​ table-row;​">​…​</tr>​]
```

Here the parent class is "level-0".
  What I am expecting is "level-0-0 ,level-0-1".
  In the regex "[-\d]+{1,1}", I am trying to specify that  level-0 should be followed by a single occurrence of '-' followed by integer. But I am not able to restrict the occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be like below,

```
/level-0-\d+\s/
```

Use word boundary if necessary.

```
/\blevel-0-\d+\s/
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash . Your solution was close but, I had to add a \s after \d for making it  working bcos the tr has 3 class names. For eg:
<tr class="fundRow level-0-0 child"></tr>

Comment: you mean this `/\blevel-0-\d+(?=\s)/` ?

Comment: Avinash, the above regex is working if I directly use inside a match. Since the class name is dynamic I am using new RegExp and this is not giving me any result.
var exp = 'level-0';
$('tr').filter(function(){
  return this.className.match(new regExp(exp+'\d+\s'))
})

Comment: then it would be `new RegExp(exp+'\\d+\\s')`

Comment: I didn't escape \d and \s